# Rebinding :b and :e in evil-normal-state-map

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

I can't figure out how to rebind the `:b` and `:e` commands in evil-mode for Emacs.  Google isn't much of a help either.

I have tried `(define-key evil-normal-state-map ":b" 'helm-buffers-list)` but that screws up the `:` key for entering commands.

Currently I'm using `(define-key evil-normal-state-map ",b" 'helm-buffers-list)` and `(define-key evil-normal-state-map ",e" 'find-file)` but I'd prefer to have them on `:b` and `:e` so the motions would be the same when using real Vim.

Please don't mention remapping to `,b` and `,e` in Vim. :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Okey, one needs to (re)define an `evil-ex-define-cmd`:

- `(evil-ex-define-cmd "b[uffer]" 'helm-buffers-list)`
- `(evil-ex-define-cmd "e[dit]" 'find-file)`

Except now they need an `<enter>` after `:<cmd>`.

**Right**, after some more trawling through the source I found the solution:

- `(define-key evil-ex-map "b" 'helm-buffers-list)`
- `(define-key evil-ex-map "e" 'find-file)`

Now no `<enter>` is needed after entering f.e. `:b`.